# properties of the dual of $H^1_0(\mathbb{R}^2;\mathbb{R}^2)$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

Consider $f(x_1,x_2)=\chi_{B_1(0,0)}(x_1,x_2)$.

1) Is $\nabla f\in (H^1_0(\mathbb{R}^2;\mathbb{R}^2))^*$?

2) $\langle \nabla f , u \rangle= ?$    with $u\in H_0^1(\mathbb{R^2})$?

For the first question I had no problem, but for the second one I have some troubles, it would be correct to use an integration by parts?

Comment: If you have doubts, use density. Take a smooth compactly supported $u$ and do all your computations. Later, one is usually able to show that the result still holds for general $u$ by density.

Comment: But even using $u\in C_0^\infty$ I don't know how to proceed because $\nabla f$ is a vector and $u$ scalar... Maybe it is a silly question, but I'm really confused

Comment: That's not really a problem. One has $$\langle \nabla f, u\rangle = \left\langle \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1}, u\right\rangle \mathbf{e}_1 +\left\langle \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_2}, u\right\rangle \mathbf{e}_2, $$where $\mathbf{e}_j$ are the standard unit vectors of $\mathbf{R}^2$ space. Just work in coordinates if vector notation confuses you.